# Storing date in two bytes

Tags: c, date, bitwise-operators

I am reading a Let us C book, in that to store date in two bytes formula is there

```
int year = 1990, month = 03, day=22

date = 512*(year-1980)+32*month+day
```

I do not understand the above formula, like why 1980 is being subtracted from given year and multiplying with 512 then multiplying 32 with month and adding day.

Could someone please explain me above formula. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pleas show the declaration of `date`. "How negative numbers store in the bits?" That is the right question - think about it.

Comment: 512 and 32 are powers-of-two. multiplying by them is the direct equivalent of a bitwise "shift left" operation. 1980 is simply this date system's "epoch" - time 0.

Comment: @MarcB: It is actually irrelevant, if these are powers of 2. They only need to be larger than the max. possible value of the lower parts.

Comment: @Olaf My actual question is  about the formula, and if i give year < 1980 it would be negative so how negative numbers store in bits.

Comment: You are not asking about representation of integer values, aren't you? Read a C or any other programming book! Search Wikipedia.

Comment: That's not a pleasant book to be reading... Is there any reason you're concerned about such a small difference in memory usage? I imagine back in the day "Let Us C" was written (it's a prehistoric book), two bytes would have been a huge deal... but in this day and age, you should probably be using a *profiler* to determine what the most significant bottlenecks in your code are and spending your precious time on those instead of wasting your time on this... Get a new book!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but this is just a way to store a date that is after the 1.1.1980, and not a very good one.

Comment: @olaf I am certain there are platforms where shift right 8 bits are significantly faster than divide by 500.

Comment: `512*(year-1980)+32*month+day` is equivalent to `(year-1980) << 9 | month << 5 | day`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above formule just store the day (1-31 or 0-30) on 5 digits, the month (0-11 or 1-12) on 4 digits  and the year on 7 digits to put it in only 2 bytes.

The *epoch* here is year 1980, that means that all will be fine for years between 1980 and 2127. My advice would be to avoid negative values and choose an appropriate start year. For example `date = 512*(year-1950)+32*month+day` would be fine for years between 1950 and 2077.

I advise you to avoid negative values because right shift of signed value is defined by standard as *implementation dependant* so you cannot know if the new bits will be filled with 1 or with 0. So even if you want to process *negative* values, always use `unsigned short` for you 2 byte values or `uint16_t` to have deterministic shifts.